# How do you get client DPI in Partial Trust XBAP?

Tags: wpf

Is it possible to get the client's DPI in a Partial Trust XBAP?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

First, here is how to get retrieve the client's DPI in WPF:

http://blogs.msdn.com/jaimer/archive/2007/03/07/getting-system-dpi-in-wpf-app.aspx

However, according to the MSDN documentation, the **PresentationSource** class requires **unrestricted UIPermission** to be granted to the code, so this makes it impossible to use it from a partial trust application running in the 'Internet' zone.